# How to find out if a method directly or indirectly calls a property?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to figure out how to avoid StackOverflowException in one of my classes, where a method indirectly calls a property that ends up calling back the method again. When this first happened, I looked up the stack trace and fixed the code, but then it happened again, in another place of the same method. I strongly suspect there are other indirect calls in that method that will cause the exception again, and so I'd like to be able to find all indirect calls to the property.

Is there some way, using Visual Studio 2010  Graphs functionality to visually assist in finding connections between a method and a property/field?

Comment: I think I'd look at detecting that it was happening in code, or refactoring so it wouldn't. Even if you sort it now, you've every chance of reintroducing the problem later on.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson Yeah, I know I've got serious problems with my code, and I'm in the process of rewriting it, and this question is about one step of it.

Comment: Use Resharper. You can get whole stack traces when clicking on the property (or its setter or getter) or a method and click Inspect -> Incoming calls. Featuring a special icon for direct recursive calls. http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Code_Analysis__Call_Tracking.html

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a graphical representation, but you can however just right click on the method and hit "Find All References", go through those calls and make sure that none of them are recursive.

Another option is debug, set a breakpoint on the method and check the call stack to identify any possible recursive calls.

Comment: I guess you mean `Find all references` and there are quite a lot of them throughout the class. I'd like to narrow it down to only one specific method.

Comment: @user1306322 Yeah that's right, ReSharper calls it Find Usages, hence the confusion! The only way you'll be able to narrow it down is either going through the usages or debugging, putting a breakpoint on the method and then checking the call stack.

Comment: Well, actually there is one rather slow way − create a dependency graph for methods and properties, search through all that spaghetti mess the property in question and filter all unconnected nodes, but that takes quite a bit of time. If only there was an easier way.